# How to add payload and use the post method to get response from an API in twincat 3?

Tags: api, payload, twincat, structured-text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDY9u.png)Not getting appropriate response like I get on the postman application

I tried a few online APIs which give me response, but I need an option to be able to add a payload in my program. I am using tc3 iotbase library from the twincat library repo.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP POST request payload is builded by the [FB_IotHttpRequest](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf6760_tc3_iot_https_rest/7643740171.html?id=8968437232422612873) function block, when you call one of the send methods

You can use 2 option here:

- [FB_IotHttpRequest.SendRequest(...)](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6760_tc3_iot_https_rest/7645369355.html&id=) in this case you need to create the payload JSON manually
- [FB_IotHttpRequest.SendJsonDomRequest(...)](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf6760_tc3_iot_https_rest/7644545035.html?id=2287731060941923431) in this case you need just pass the reference of the [FB_JsonDomParser](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf6760_tc3_iot_https_rest/7643740171.html?id=8968437232422612873), which contains the json document.